# Table row redirect using onclick attr

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to redirect using the TR attr "onclick" to be able to go to other page?

i actually tried it but im having page error.

Answer (score 2):

```
<tr onclick="window.location = 'http://ubuntu.com'">
   <td>some text</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple DOM or with jQuery:

```
$("tr").click(function() {
  window.location = 'your_location';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Or in straight js!

```
var tr = document.getElementById('tr-id');
tr.onclick = function (e) {
  location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
};
```